# I need a simple equation to measure a efficiency of attempts correction

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a process where the user need correct an invalid information in your registry within a maximum number of attempts. The closer he gets this maximum number, the worse your rate.

For example:

**1st attempt of 5: 100% of accuracy**

**5th attempt of 5: 0% of accuracy**

Is there a simple equation to resolve this, so I tell the 'current attempt' and the 'total attempts allowed' and returns the accuracy rate?

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a linear relation the function is $f(x)=mx+b$.

And you have two conditions:

$f(1)=1 \ (=100\%)$

$f(5)=0 \ (0\%)$

Thus the explicit equations are:

$1=m+b$

$0=5m+b$

Solving for m and b gives $m=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $b=\frac{5}{4}$.